# How to add an empty, editable column to a Taipy's GUI table?

Tags: python, user-interface, taipy

I had a question regarding the On_add function for a table. In the following link there is an example of how to add an empty and editable row in a taipy table. I was wondering if it was possible to add an empty, editable column to a table in taipy.

In the example provided: https://www.taipy.io/tips/using-tables/

It's possible to add an empty editable row...

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it is possible to add an empty, editable column to a table in Taipy GUI applications. I will be using the same code in the article that you included, and I will add a new **food_df_on_add_column** function regarding the **on_add** property of the table. Note that we will also need to set the table's **rebuild** property to **True** in order to refresh the columns.

Here is the code:

---

```
from taipy.gui import Gui

import pandas as pd

food_df = pd.DataFrame({

"Meal": ["Lunch", "Dinner", "Lunch", "Lunch", "Breakfast", "Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner"],

"Category": ["Food", "Food", "Drink", "Food", "Food", "Drink", "Dessert", "Dessert"],

"Name": ["Burger", "Pizza", "Soda", "Salad", "Pasta", "Water", "Ice Cream", "Cake"],

"Calories": [300, 400, 150, 200, 500, 0, 400, 500],

})

def food_df_on_add_column(state):

    df = state.food_df

    # Adding a new column with None values

    df['NewColumn'] = None

    #Replacing the used df

    state.food_df = df

main_md = "<|{food_df}|table|rebuild=True|on_add=food_df_on_add_column|>"

Gui(page=main_md).run(dark_mode=False)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you need to identify row index number and this row column name.

if you can send this 2 argument in controller/function via request then fetch only this row after fetched this row then update specific column value.

```
UPDATE `users` SET `name` = 'HRM' WHERE `users`.`id` = 4;
 
 [enter image description here][1]
```